# Can't use function return value in write context error using Laravel 4

Tags: forms, laravel-4

I got an error when I try to add a private variable value to hidden input with Laravel 4

```
Can't use function return value in write context
```

This my code  :

```
$form =  Form::open(array('url' => $actionUrl))
      .= Form::hidden('storeId',  $this->_store_id)
 .=  Form::close();

   return $form;
```

I got this error on this line :

```
   .= Form::hidden('storeId',  $this->_store_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write your code like this:

```
$form  = Form::open(array('url' => $actionUrl));
$form .= Form::hidden('storeId',  $this->_store_id);
$form .= Form::close();
return $form;
```

P/S: Where are you writing this code and for what reason? You should generate a `form` in view directly.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and updating PHP version to 5.5.x fixed it for me.

Answer (score -1):

I also got this error "Can't use function return value in write context error using Laravel 4"

Due to 
**if(!empty($errors->first('title'))){
something....
}**

We can not use function inside of empty function in **prior PHP 5.5 Version**. It gives error
So, you can use 
**if($errors->first('title') != ''){ something...}**

I think, you have used function inside of empty function.
:)